# How to edit XML file using Python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a list of `XML` documents with the following structure. I need to delete this line:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">
```

using Python code, as manually deleting it would be very time consuming as there lots of files.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">

<pdf2xml producer="poppler" version="0.62.0">
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1262" width="892">

</page>
</pdf2xml>
```

Comment: which line you want to delete?

Comment: @MikiBelavista: See question now, I fixed a formatting issue that was hiding the line.

Comment: @MikiBelavista Line 2 `<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read files line by line and then write them back without the line you don't want in the file. Just be sure what you want to delete - is it exactly the line you wrote? Is it always the second line? Is every `!DOCTYPE` line? Is it first `!DOCTYPE` line? Etc.

```
import os
import sys

# Assumes first argument when running the script is a directory containing XML files
directory = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "."
files = os.listdir(directory)

for f in files:
    # Ignore not XML files
    if not f.endswith(".xml"):
        continue

    # Read file content
    with open(f, 'r') as f_in:
        content = f_in.readlines()

    # Rewrite the original file
    with open(f, 'w') as f_out:
        for line in content:
            # The condition may differ based on what you really want to delete
            if line != "<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM \"pdf2xml.dtd\">\n":
                f_out.write(line)
```

**Things to consider:**

1. If the files are big you may not want to load them into the memory
2. It is inefficient for example in case you want to always delete just the second line in the file.
3. Do you really need/want to use Python for that? There are better solutions. For example, if you are on Linux or Mac you can use `sed`:

   ```
   for f in *.xml; do sed -i '' -n '/<!DOCTYPE pdf2xml SYSTEM "pdf2xml.dtd">/!p' $f; done
   ```

Comment: You are the saviour

Answer (score 0):

First, open the file:

```
f = open("yourfile.txt","r")
```

Next, get all your lines from the file:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

Now you can close the file:

```
f.close()
```

And reopen it in write mode:

```
f = open("yourfile.txt","w")
```

Then, write your lines back, except the line you want to delete. You might want to change the  "\n" to whatever line ending your file uses.

```
for line in lines:
  if not line.startswith('<!DOCTYPE'):
    f.write(line)
```

At the end, close the file again.

```
f.close()
```